# Hiding Divtag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on span, I want to hide the div tag under it, but my code doesn't work. I'd like to hear your opinion on how to reconstruct the jQuery code.

```js
    $(document).on("click", ".show-table-bottom > span", function() {
      if ($(this).next().css("display") == "none") {
        $(this).next().show();
      } else {
        $(this).next().hide();
      }
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="show-table-bottom" colspan=3 style="height:65%; vertical-align: top; padding:2%;">
          <span>번역</span>
          <div style="display:none; border:1px dashed gray;">
            <div>
              <br>
              <h4><b>ASDSA</b></h4><br><br><br><br> aSDASD
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Assuming your `td` is inside a `table` (as it has to be for HTML validity) then your code works fine. The minor only issue was that you missed the `</span>`. I've edited a snippet in to your question which works as expected. If you still have issues, please check the console for errors

Comment: Thank you. A lot of advice.
!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify the logic and just use.toggle() on the click of the span. .toggle() toggles the visibility between display: block and dispaly: none - so you don't need the conditional logic.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".show-table-bottom > span", function() { $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="show-table-bottom" colspan=3 style="height:65%; vertical-align: top; padding:2%;">
      <span>번역</span>
      <div style="display:none; border:1px dashed gray;">
        <div>
          <br>
          <h4><b>ASDSA</b></h4><br><br><br><br> aSDASD
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define hide class in style and then use jquery function **toggleClass()** to use toggle hide class

```
<style>
.hide{
display:none;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".show-table-bottom > span", function() {
      $(this).next('div').toggleClass('hide');
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps you